# break d date from yyyy-mm-dd into mm,yyyy and dd as separate elements

Tags: php, mysql, date, date-format, date-conversion

I am storing the date in MySQL in the format yyyy-mm-dd. I wish to extract individual elements of the date i.e. day,month and year as separate elements

How should I go about this?
I am using php

Comment: `DAY(date)`, `MONTH(date)` and `YEAR(date)` MySQL Functions

Comment: if you're doing the sensible thing, and storign it in a [`DATE` or `DATETIME` field](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html), then it's simply a case of querying `MONTH(fieldname)`, etc. If you're storing it as a string, then you'll have to `explode()` it into pieces and work on them, but do yourself a favour and use a `DATETIME` field. That's what it's there for.

Comment: `sscanf($date, '%d-%d-%d', $Y, $m, $d);` or `list($Y, $m, $d) = explode('-', $date);`

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of the **`DateTime`** class which has the [`createFromFormat`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php).

Like this..

```
<?php
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2009-02-23');
echo $date->format('Y');//2009
echo $date->format('F');//February or use 'M' for Feb
echo $date->format('d');//23
```

Comment: Thanks.. Suppose if I want to generalise the above to get all the twelve months should I use a loop or something? Can you please help me with this?? Becasue my date comes from database

Comment: Whatever you are retrieving from the rows to PHP will be intrepreted as a string , so you can directly pass it.. and yeah you can loop it too.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using explode function in php.
explode('-', $date_obj);